# Angular velocity of a pendulum in Cartesian coordinates

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, coordinate-systems, angular-velocity

Hello I have a problem how to write down equations for the pendulum correctly. Say I would use Cartesian coordinates $x, y$ representing the position of the mass. Then the velocities would be usually written as $\dot{x}, \dot{y}$, but here the problem appears.

Of course, the pendulum may move in two different directions at every position. So I think there should be two signs $\pm \dot{x}, \pm \dot{y}$, but $x, y$ have only a single sign. If polar coordinates are used this is realized with the angular velocity that is a pseudo quantity. Is it also possible using Cartesian coordinates to incorporate this somehow?

Comment: Why do $x$ and $y$ only have a single sign?

Comment: The velocity at any $(x(t),y(t))$ point is just $(\dot{x}(t), \dot{y}(t))$, simple as that. Any positive or negative signs can contained in $\dot{x}(t)/\dot{y}(t)$ without any need to assign an explicited sign to them.

Comment: Oh you are right, I mean a single sign for each of them. Not necessarily the same of course.

Comment: I don't understand what your problem is. Please give a concrete example where the math gives an incorrect answer unless the signs are flipped manually.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are overcomplicating the problem. If the mass is located at

$$ \begin{matrix} x = \ell \sin \theta \\ y = -\ell \cos \theta \end{matrix} $$

relative to the pivot point then, the velocity kinematics are

$$ \begin{matrix} \dot x = \ell \dot{\theta} \cos \theta \\ \dot{y} = \ell \dot{\theta} \sin \theta \end{matrix} $$

The values of $\dot{x}$ and $\dot{y}$ may be positive meaning motion to the right and up or negative menaing motion left or down. The same sign convention applies for the coordinates $(x,y)$ as for their derivatives $(\dot{x}, \dot{y})$.

Comment: Okay, but I don't see it. You are right, but the problem is still there. Say for example in your equations that we are in the fourth quadrant (x > 0, y < 0). Then $x = +x$, but $\dot{x} = \pm \dot{x}$ (sign is in $\dot{\theta}$). Now, if you do not have $\dot{\theta}$ because you use Cartesian coordinates, then I would have $x = +x$, but $\frac{d}{dt} x = \pm \dot{x}$. But this is strange, since taking a derivative usually is not adding a second sign.

Comment: You know it is ok to have $x>0$ and $\dot{x}<0$. The mechanics of the problem are such that the velocity _vector_ is always perpendicular to the position _vector_. So if the position is on the 4th quadrant, then the velocity will point towards the 1st quadrant. Go outside and observe a swing, and visualize the velocty vector. You will see how the math works out.